# Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib - can it be due to image="imageView:"

Tags: ios, error-handling, swift4, xcode9

I've tried various tips for identifying the source of this error in my code. But so far unsuccessful. It happens when i load a new ViewController, so I assume it has something to do with the assets that I use.

I can't find any errors with any of the images.. any tips on what I can do to solve this?

The error I get is

```
2017-11-25 14:44:12.824454+0100 Shoota[56975:18283319] [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: ''
2017-11-25 14:44:12.824640+0100 Shoota[56975:18283319] Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "Ctech.Shoota"
2017-11-25 14:44:12.843855+0100 Shoota[56975:18283319] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f8e5260ee90> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key birdView.'
```

I've looked at the source code of the Main.storyboard and for the relevant ViewController. I found these image references... Can this be the source of error?

```
<imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="imageView:4hW-wf-T7e:image" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4hW-wf-T7e">
   <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="140" width="349" height="1"/>
      <constraints>
          <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="1" id="m11-ek-CKC"/>
      </constraints>
</imageView>
```

Comment: Do you have image with name `imageView:4hW-wf-T7e:image` in your assets file?

Comment: @trungduc: Yes I found the two in IB. Thanks. However there is still a last error with the UIViewController 0x78e5260ee90 - how do I find out which view controller this is?

Comment: Let try press `Command + 4` and search `imageView:4hW-wf-T7e:image`. It will list files which use this image.